# Why won't Banshee Boot after an unexpected power outage?

Tags: 11.10, banshee

I was in the middle of rescanning my audio library on my desktop pc when the power was cut unexpectedly.

My system seems to be fine overall except for Banshee which throws up an error which I will post at the bottom of this question.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled banshee to no effect and am unsure how to proceed other than find an alternate player, this would be possible but not favorable.

---

```
An unhandled exception was thrown: Document element did not appear. file:///home/matt/.config/banshee-1/addin-db-001/config.xml Line 1, position 1.

  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml.EntityResolvingXmlReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml.DTDValidatingReader.ReadContent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml.DTDValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml.Schema.XsdValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNodeCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNode (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.String filename) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Addins.Database.DatabaseConfiguration.Read (System.String file) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Addins.Database.AddinDatabase.get_Configuration () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Addins.Database.AddinDatabase.RunPendingUninstalls (IProgressStatus monitor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Addins.Database.AddinDatabase.Update (IProgressStatus monitor, System.String domain) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Addins.AddinRegistry.Update (IProgressStatus monitor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.InitializeAddins () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.DefaultInitialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.Application.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Initialize (Boolean registerCommonServices) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient..ctor (Boolean initializeDefault, System.String defaultIconName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Nereid.Client..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Gui.CleanRoomStartup.Startup (Hyena.Gui.StartupInvocationHandler startup) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1
OS Version: Unix 3.0.0.12

Assembly Version Information:

System.Xml (4.0.0.0)
Banshee.Core (2.2.0.0)
Hyena.Data.Sqlite (2.2.0.0)
gdk-sharp (2.12.0.0)
Mono.Addins (0.6.0.0)
atk-sharp (2.12.0.0)
Hyena.Gui (2.2.0.0)
Mono.Posix (4.0.0.0)
gtk-sharp (2.12.0.0)
Banshee.ThickClient (2.2.0.0)
Nereid (2.2.0.0)
DBus.Proxies (0.0.0.0)
System.Core (4.0.0.0)
Hyena (2.2.0.0)
dbus-sharp (1.0.0.0)
glib-sharp (2.12.0.0)
System (4.0.0.0)
Banshee.Services (2.2.0.0)
Banshee (2.2.0.0)
mscorlib (4.0.0.0)

Platform Information: Linux 3.0.0-12-generic x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Disribution Information:

[/etc/lsb-release]
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"

[/etc/debian_version]
wheezy/sid
```

---

Comment: If you haven't had any luck with this yet, I'd be sure to take a look at the answer by @s666 below.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to purge banshee?

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge banshee
```

It seems as if a configuration file was not found. It might be possible that it was not to be deleted while uninstalling normally and therefore was not reinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
cd ~/.config/banshee-1
sqlite3 banshee.db ".dump" > dump
mv banshee.db banshee.db.backup
cat dump | sqlite3 banshee.db
```

if not have a read of this http://banshee.fm/support/faq/

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing. This command usually works in cases where you see a "database disk image is malformed" error in the log, but it may also work in this case. Definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem solved by deleting the corrupted database.

Type this in a terminal

- `cd ~/.config/banshee-1`
- `rm banshee.db`
- `rm -r addin*`

Then close it and start banshee again